# How do I fix this "cannot find symbol error"?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

My code is "complete" but I'm having trouble with the error:

> "Cannot find symbol"

```
import java.util.*;
public class OrderNumbers
{
 public static void main (String [] args)
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int input1;
int input2;
int input3;

System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
input1 = scan.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
input2 = scan.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter the third number: ");
input3 = scan.nextInt();
}   

 {if ((input1 > input2 && input1 > input3))

 { if (input2 > input3)
 {
 System.out.print(input3 + "," + input2 + "," + input1);
 }
 else
 System.out.print(input2 + "," + input3 + "," +input1);
 }
  else if ((input2 > input1 && input2 > input3))


{if (input1 > input3)
{
System.out.print(input3 + "," + input1 + "," + input2);
}
 else
 {
 System.out.print(input1 + "," + input3 + "," + input2);
}
 }
 else if ((input3 > input1 && input3 > input2))

{if (input1 > input2)
{
System.out.print(input2 + "," + input1 + "," + input3);
}
else
System.out.print(input1 + "," + input2 + "," + input3);
 }
 else
 {
   System.out.println("ERROR!");

  }
}
  }
```

I've read plenty of forums and it seems that the common issue is that most people are not declaring in the right space, but I do believe I am.

Comment: format your code.then you will be able to answer your question

Comment: What is the complete error you're receiving? Which symbol can it not find? Is your code after `input3 = scan.nextInt();` and the closing brace even contained within a function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You have extra closing braces that close your `main` method after the scanner statements.

```
}   

 {if ((input1 > input2 && input1 > input3))
```

Remove these `{` `}` and the problem will be fixed.

---

That said, **format your code**, which is easy if you **use an IDE such as [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/home/index.php)**. This is what your code looks like after using <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F</kbd> on this code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class OrderNumbers {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input1;
    int input2;
    int input3;

    System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
    input1 = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
    input2 = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the third number: ");
    input3 = scan.nextInt();
  }

  {
    if ((input1 > input2 && input1 > input3))

    {
      if (input2 > input3) {
        System.out.print(input3 + "," + input2 + "," + input1);
      } else
        System.out.print(input2 + "," + input3 + "," + input1);
    } else if ((input2 > input1 && input2 > input3))

    {
      if (input1 > input3) {
        System.out.print(input3 + "," + input1 + "," + input2);
      } else {
        System.out.print(input1 + "," + input3 + "," + input2);
      }
    } else if ((input3 > input1 && input3 > input2))

    {
      if (input1 > input2) {
        System.out.print(input2 + "," + input1 + "," + input3);
      } else
        System.out.print(input1 + "," + input2 + "," + input3);
    } else {
      System.out.println("ERROR!");

    }
  }
}
```

Do you see how much more obvious the problem is when your code is formatted?